# How can bind .click() event to any dynamically created Raphael object in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

update: I have run this code and checked Chrome Console for any errors or warnings. None found.

I wrote the following code to draw a circle using Raphael.

The idea is to have one big red circle with a `.click()` event registered to create additional small green circles.

For some reason, chrome does not trigger `.click()` events for those smaller green circles that were created in the `.click()` event of the first big red circle. While Internet Explorer does. Even **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6j4V/4/)** worked fine while being browsed in Chrome. But the code won't work if run entirely local.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Raphael Test</title>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script/raphael.js"></script>
    <script>
        var x = 100;    /* to offset x position for dynamically created */

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var paper = Raphael('holder');
            var circle = paper.circle(300,300,100);
            circle.attr("fill","red");
            circle.click(function(){
                var inner=paper.circle(x+=100,100,20).attr("fill","green");
                inner.attr("stroke-width","4");
                /* The following code has no effect whatsoever !!!*/
                inner.click(function(){
                    alert('green circle clicked');
                });
            });
    });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="holder" style="background-color:whitesmoke;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried to have the click event declared in advanced and pass the function name to the .click() of the created object but that did not work.

I tried to declare the `inner` variable out of the scope of the red `circle` so that I can later add event listener to it but that also did not work.

How can I create an object and attach .click() event to it?

Comment: Any error in chrome console? Any online link which replicate your issue? Silly question but have you clear chrome cache?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium, sure there is nothing missing when using it locally ?

Comment: @Ian I have checked the chrome console for errors or warnings. Nothing came up.

Comment: @A.Wolff  I have checked the chrome console for errors or warnings. Nothing came up.

Comment: @Ahmad And what about chrome cache?!

Comment: what is chrome cache? @A.Wolff

Comment: I'm talking about browser's cache...

Comment: I refreshed the page multiple times. How can I tell if chrome is loading the page from cache or not? @A.Wolff

Comment: Well, what about using google, I'm not your search engine. You have to take some initiative on your side if you want to learn something. Now try on you page to press `ctrl + F5` or `ctrl+shift+del`. Anyway, as i see it, shouldn't be a cache issue. Again, if you want specific help, at least try to replicate your issue online or pass link where your issue can be checked otherwise we can just guessing you are doing something wrong, somewhere